# Azure Web App: HTTP Error 500 on favicon.ico

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, azure-diagnostics

I often get the following 500 server error after publishing to my Azure Web App.

If I delete the web app, recreate it, and republish, everything is fine again.

I retrieved the following error page by turning on diagnostics (in the Azure Portal) and locating the detailed error page in Visual Studio 2015's Cloud Explorer:

[image: DetailedError]

**Error Page:**

> **HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error**
>
> The page cannot be displayed
>   because an internal server error has occurred.
>
> **Most likely causes:**
>
> - IIS received the request; however, an internal
>     error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of
>     this error depends on which module handles the request and what was
>     happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
> - IIS was not
>     able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application.
>     This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
> - IIS was
>     not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
> - The
>     authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
> - The
>     request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility
>     Feature is not installed.
>
> **Things you can try:**
>
> - Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the
>     web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's
>     machine account.
> - Check the event logs to see if any additional
>     information was logged.
> - Verify the permissions for the DLL.
> - Install
>     the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed
>     handler.
> - Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP
>     status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for
>     failed requests, click here.
>
> **Detailed Error Information:**
>
> **Module**       ManagedPipelineHandler
>
> **Notification**     MapRequestHandler
>
> **Handler**      StaticFile
>
> **Error Code**      0x00000000
>
> **Requested URL**    http://myurl:80/favicon.ico
>
> **Physical Path** D:\home\site\wwwroot\favicon.ico
>
> **Logon Method**     Anonymous
>
> **Logon User**    Anonymous

There seems to be an issue with resolving favicon.ico.  I have included and excluded this from the wwwroot deployment but with no difference.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

**NOTE:** I am using [the following publish script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5) from MSDN if it matters.

This is related to one of my [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992141/show-asp-net-5-error-page-in-azure-web-app).

Comment: I'm getting the same issue right now and it's really annoying. I can push my code just fine, no errors in that process; but once i try to go to the website i get a 500 error. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

With ASP.NET 5 it can be hard to capture the error. In your `Startup.cs` file, you have a `Configure` method. Wrap everything within the `Configure` method into a `try-catch` block like this. Then you can slowly build out your app and see when it blows. At least you'll know that it is not in the `Configure` method or if it is, then you'll now which bit of additional functionality blew it. You can use this strategy in other methods too.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // HACK: for Azure web apps,
    // the try-catch block lets us see errors that occur during configuration
    try
    {
        app.UseErrorPage();
        app.UseRuntimeInfoPage();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // add in remaining functionality one bit at a time...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(ex.ToString());
        });
    }

    // Run on each request
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hooray. It didn't error out.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely I have a difficult problem?  The error page I have is complaining about favicon.ico.

Answer (score 1):

My problem ended up being that I had enabled the Help area for my API and had it set to use the auto-generated XML, but hadn't included that XML file in my solution (so it wasn't being published to azure). Not sure why it complains about the favicon though.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is little confusing. The real problem is with Startup.cs. You have to dicover it by turning on application in developer mode:
[Show ASP.NET 5 error page in Azure web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992141/show-asp-net-5-error-page-in-azure-web-app?lq=1)